Can Apache fury serialize a Java undirected graph (relations with cycles)?
Can Apache fury https://fury.apache.org serialize a Java undirected graph (relations with cycles)? I.e can I use it to replace all Java serialization usage?

Yes, you can use it to serialize all java objects. Apache Fury supports serialize circular reference and is compatible with all Java serialization api such as writeObject/writeReplace/readObject/readResolve/Externalizable.
If you want to serialize circular reference, please create Fury with reference tracking enabled. It's disabled by default.
ThreadSafeFury fury = Fury.builder().withRefTracking(true).buildThreadSafeFury();

